# 502 Bad Gateway, nginx error on AWS EC2 instance after restoring from AWS backup

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I had some troubles with my website hosted on AWS EC2, so I restored it from a recent backup in AWS backup. Since doing that, it would go to the main page fine, but if I try to go to the login page, it returns a "502 Bad Gateway". This website was set up by my colleague who has since left, I am familiar with Python but the website stuff not so much, so I'm a bit in the dark as to where to start looking, any insights would be much appreciated. I am looking at the nginx error log but not sure what I am looking at/looking for.

The system uses:

- django
- nginx
- gunicorn

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't give any information that would allow us to help you. 502 means that the proxy layer (probably nginx in your case) cannot connect to the back-end server (probably, django).

Comment: Thanks, yeah unfortunately this is quite a new area to me, I am happy to provide more information if I could get some guidance as to what I should be providing, e.g. is the nginx error log the right place to start?